# no route matches create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

HERE IS MY new.html.erb FILE BELOW

```
<%= form_for(:subject, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
```

i just want to insert a record in my database.

Here is my subjectscontroller.rb file below

```
end
```

Here is my route.rb file below

```
get "subjects/create"
```

When i run localhost:3000/subjects/new it runs perfectly. And then I try to insert a value through text boxes and when i click on Create subject button of my form it gives me no route matches create.Please solve my problem as soon as possible otherwise i am in deep trouble

Comment: Deep trouble?  Sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 3):

You've defined a route which responds to an HTTP GET.  When submitting the form, you send an HTTP POST.  That's the source of your current error message.

Before panicking, take a few minutes to read through this [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) on routing.  I think it will help clarify how to proceed.

Comment: please do some other help it does not work for me.is there anything i use instead of url..please please help me ia ma in trouble guys

Answer (score 0):

You should add the subjects to the routes as resources .

```
AppName::Application.routes.draw do 
 resources :subjects
 root :to => "demo#index"
 get ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end
```

Your controller should be like this

```
def create
 @subject = Subject.new(subject_params)
 if @subject.save
   redirect_to(:action => 'list')
 else
   render('new')
 end
end

private
def subject_params
  params.require(:subject).permit(:id, :name, :position, :visible)
end
```

It should work.